# SQL Server Analysis Services Ports

Tags: sql-server, port, ssas, ssms, firewall

When I am on **Server1** and try to connect to analysis services on **Server2** it does not work, and I cannot telnet to **Server2** on port 2383 either...

**BUT**

When I am on **Server1** and I open up a database connection via SSMS to **Server2** and then try and connect to analysis services on **Server2** it works!

***Is anyone aware why this could possibly happen ?***

Comment: You check the firewall? How do you know it is on port 2383? That's the default but it could have been changed.

Comment: It has not been changed, that is the port. You are missing the point - I can access SSAS but only after opening a DB Connection in SSMS

Comment: That's odd. Is it only after the server first restarts? If you disconnect from the DB connection does the SSAS connection stop letting you connect?

Comment: No, it's all the time. If I disconnect the SSMS session, it continues to work. When I completely log off from the server and go in and do it again, I have to go through the same process